# php foreach [category tiltes displays for each text list, even from same category]

Tags: php, foreach

Sorry for this really simple php question.

I have a site in php and want to echo the category and text lists.
When I write something like this...

```
<?php foreach ($reports as $report): ?>   
<h3><?php echo h($report["category_title"]); ?></h3>  
<ul>
  <li><?php echo h($report["text"]); ?></a></li>
</ul> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It shows me something like this..

Category Title 1

Text 1

Category Title 1

Text 2

Category Title 2

Text 3

Category Title 2

Text 4

**My question is how can I have this shown as something like..**

Category Title 1

Text 1

Text 2

Category Title 2

Text 3

Text 4

Appreciate a lot if someone could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternative solution, using [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies). [`Arrays::groupBy`](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/arrays.html#groupby) method:

```
$reports = Arrays::groupBy($reports, Functions::extract()->category_title);
foreach ($reports as $category => $report) {
    echo '<h3>' . $category . '</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($report as $element) {
        echo '<li>' . $element['text'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And result:

```
<h3>category1</h3>
<ul>
<li>title1</li>
<li>title2</li>
</ul>
<h3>category2</h3>
<ul>
<li>title1</li>
<li>title2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable called `$currentCat` and check if the category title changes:

```
<?php 
$currentCat = false;
foreach ($reports as $report):
    if ($currentCat !== $report[category_title]):
        if ($currentCat)
            echo '</ul>';
?>   
<h3><?php echo h($report[category_title]); ?></h3>
<ul>
<?php
        $currentCat = $report[category_title];
    endif;
?>
<li><?php echo h($report["text"]); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;

if ($currentCat)
        echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be in how the data is stored. I assume that you $reports is like this

```
$reports = [
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 1', 'text' => 'text 1'],
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 1', 'text' => 'text 2'],
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 2', 'text' => 'text 1'],
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 2', 'text' => 'text 2'],
];
```

You shouldn't duplicate the category_title information. Your $reports var should look like this.

```
$reports = [
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 1', 'texts' => ['text 1', 'text 2']]
    ['category_title' => 'Category title 2', 'texts' => ['text 1', 'text 2']]
];
```

You can convert from one array to another like this.

```
$new_reports = [];
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    if(!isset($new_report[$report['category_title']])) {
        $new_report['category_title'] = [];
    }
    $new_report['category_title'] []= $report['text'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jordi. Really appreciated your kindness!